# Android Application Crashed when adding buttons

Tags: android, fatal-error

I had my app up and running about 2 weeks ago. Didn't change anything except adding two buttons to help the user retrun to a main screen. However, when I run my app now, I get the following error:

```
    02-03 14:01:28.206 12937-12937/com.example.cherryjp.buttonapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 14:01:28.206 12937-12937/com.example.cherryjp.buttonapp 
E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.cherryjp.buttonapp, PID: 12937
02-03 14:01:28.206 12937-12937/com.example.cherryjp.buttonapp 
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cherryjp.buttonapp/com.example.cherryjp.buttonapp.ImmediateGraph}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4
02-03 14:01:28.206 12937-12937/com.example.cherryjp.buttonapp 
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
```

here's what's called when the app crashes:

```
public void showGraph(Entry entry){
    Intent immediateGraphIntent = new Intent(this, ImmediateGraph.class);

    final int result = 1;

    //Just getEntry on next intent instead of storing extras.
    immediateGraphIntent.putExtra("ENTRY_ID", entry.getId());

    //immediateGraphIntent.putExtra("PASSTIME", timeArray);
    //immediateGraphIntent.putExtra("PASSFORCE", forceArray);

    startActivity(immediateGraphIntent);

}
```

Comment: The important part of the error is `NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4`

Comment: post your onCreate or where you use String Resource ID

Comment: Post the `onCreate()` method of  `ImmediateGraph` activity.